# What is estimated probability(probas_pred) in sklearn.metrics.precision_recall_curve?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, precision-recall

`sklearn.metrics.precision_recall_curve` requires y_true and probas_pred as inputs.
I think to calculate precision and recall we need true labels (y_true) and predicted labels (y_predict).
So why does sklearn require probas_pred? How can I obtain probas_pred from y_predict?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you check out the [sklearn help page on precision-recall](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_precision_recall.html), it writes:

> The precision-recall curve shows the tradeoff between precision and
> recall for different threshold. A high area under the curve represents
> both high recall and high precision, where high precision relates to a
> low false positive rate, and high recall relates to a low false
> negative rate

Normally when you use just true labels and predicted labels, you are evaluating precision or other metrics at a threshold say 0.5 and calculating the precision from there.

If for example we increase the threshold to 0.6, that is p>0.6 will be positive class and others negative, we expect less false positive, but we'll also lose some.

You use predict_proba method to get the probabilities. For 2 class classification, the second column is the probability of the positive class which is what you need:

```
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.svm import SVC
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.metrics import precision_recall_curve

dat = datasets.load_breast_cancer()
X = dat.data
y = dat.target
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y,train_size=0.5)

clf = SVC(probability=True)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_score = clf.predict_proba(X_test)[:,1]

precision, recall, _ = precision_recall_curve(y_test,y_score)

plt.step(recall, precision, where='post')
plt.ylim([0.0, 1.05])
plt.xlim([0.0, 1.0])
```

[image]